# Monotouch - wrong screen size after rotation?

Tags: ipad, xamarin.ios, rotation

Encountered weird issue with Monotouch, not sure when did this got broken.

Basically, if I rotate iPad from portrait to landscape UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height is still reported as 1024 and UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width as 768.

Unless I'm mistaken, but shouldn't this be updated upon rotation?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I'm wrong, it's by design by Apple, nothing wrong with Monotouch.